# Escape Character while using @

Tags: c#, escaping, multiline, console.writeline

In C# im using:

```
Console.WriteLine(@"Line 0
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
\"Escape these quotes!\"
Line 5
")
```

I want to escape these quotes, but have not found out how to yet.

I'm trying out a few ideas now, but hopefully someone already knows.

Mona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait, found it out: just need to double the quotes:

```
Console.WriteLine(@"Line 0
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
""Escape these quotes!""
Line 5
")
```

Anyhow thanks!